# Slow FeatureClass Sort

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine

I am passing in a geofeatureLayer to a method that creates a UniqueValueRenderer.
I am using the following code to sort that renderer so my values will be in some kind of order. This seems very slow, however. Is there a faster way to sort a featureClass?

```
IFeatureClass featureClass = geoFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;
ITableSort tableSort = new TableSortClass();
tableSort.Table = featureClass as ITable;
tableSort.Cursor = featureCursor as ICursor;
tableSort.Fields = classifyParms.ClassifyField.Name;
tableSort.set_Ascending(classifyParms.ClassifyField.Name, true);
tableSort.Sort(null);
featureCursor = tableSort.Rows as IFeatureCursor;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh man, I could write an entire blog post on this.

Years ago, while at ESRI, I changed the internal implementation of TableSort to push the sorting to the database.

The original implementation did a simple client side [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) with some extra logic that allows paging for a lot of items to be sorted. The optimization was to detect certain usage conditions and just push the query to the database and do a [SQL order by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) directly.

As it turns out, because of the way the API was originally laid out, there are certain scenarios that will cause this optimization to not be hit (i.e pull all the data client side and to it there - potentially SLOW).

For example, if you ask for a call back, then that means that you want progress, and since there is not progress from a SQL ORDER BY, then ArcObjects relies on client side heap sort.

Another scenario is what you are doing - passing by a cursor to sort on.

```
 tableSort.Cursor = featureCursor as ICursor;
```

Unless you need to do this, **don't do it.**

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you do hit the optimization and push the sorting to the db, then you may want to have an index on the sort field so that you can leverage that.

Comment: This works (does it run in the database?)

ITableSort tableSort = new TableSortClass(); tableSort.Table = featureClass as ITable; tableSort.Fields = classifyParms.ClassifyField.Qualified; tableSort.set_Ascending( classifyParms.ClassifyField.Qualified, true ); tableSort.Sort( null ); featureCursor = tableSort.Rows as IFeatureCursor;

Comment: @chaz You are not passing the cursor to sort on or asking for progress as it goes, so the answer is yes

Comment: Here's something interesting. In one program that uses the modified routine (without assigning the cursor) it has stopped allowing the TableSort.Row to be assigned to a IFeatureCursor. (ICursor works fine and gives me what I need.) In another program with the same code (I can find no material difference) it still works with a FeatureCursor. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

The [Sorting tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001mn000000.htm) topic in the SDK help has a good overview of using the TableSort class. In your case you would probably want to do something like this:

```cs
ITableSort tableSort = new TableSortClass();
tableSort.Table = (ITable)geoFeatureLayer;
tableSort.Fields = classifyParms.ClassifyField.Name;
tableSort.set_Ascending(classifyParms.ClassifyField.Name, true);
tableSort.Sort(null);
featureCursor = tableSort.Rows as IFeatureCursor;
```

You want to use the feature layer instead of the feature class in case the layer has joined fields, a definition query, etc.

Comment: When I leave out: "tableSort.Cursor = featureCursor as ICursor;" then "featureCursor = tableSort.Rows as IFeatureCursor;" returns null. I discovered this when I first tried to implement the sort. Don't pass a cursor - don't get a cursor back. I'm using the cursor to iterate thru the data. What will fix this?