# Passing an ICursor to ArcObjects ITableSort

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, sorting

I'm trying to pass a cursor (from a `querydef` with a `prefixclause` of `DISTINCT`) to `itablesort.cursor`. I've read [another post on GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20837/slow-featureclass-sort) on the same subject that warned against doing this. That post is 4 years old -- has anything changed since then? My code works without using the cursor but it is slow when working with larger datasets. Hence why I want to use the `querydef`.

Here's excerpt of the code. The `GFLayer` at the beginning is an `iGeoFeatureLayer` pointing to a file GDB featureclass.  If I comment out the line, `.Cursor = pTblCursor`, everything runs without error.

```
Dim pDataset As IDataset = pGFLayer.FeatureClass
Dim pPosCursor As ICursor = Nothing
Dim pTblCursor As ICursor

Dim pWS As IFeatureWorkspace = pDataset.Workspace
Dim pQueryDef As IQueryDef2 = pWS.CreateQueryDef
pTblSort = New TableSort

If pGFLayer.FeatureClass.FindField("SYM") = -1 Then
    MsgBox(pGFLayer.Name + " does not have a SYM field.  Layer will not be processed.")
    pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
    Continue While
End If
With pQueryDef
    .PrefixClause = "DISTINCT"
    .Tables = pDataset.Name
    .SubFields = "POS,SYM"
    .WhereClause = ""
    pTblCursor = .Evaluate
End With

If Not pTblCursor Is Nothing Then
    With pTblSort
        .Cursor = pTblCursor
        .Table = pGFLayer.FeatureClass
        .Fields = "POS"
        .Ascending("POS") = True
    End With
    pTblSort.Sort(Nothing)
    pPosCursor = pTblSort.Rows
End If
```

Comment: what version of ArcGIS/ArcObjects are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem with 10.2 and 10.3.  To elaborate a little, when I run my code in debug, itablesort.cursor = icursor is ok  -- fails on itablesort.sort method after that.

Comment: Can you post your code?